# Using UIMA for text extraction from XML file

Tags: xml, uima

I am building a text extractor for XML using UIMA. As I am a total beginner to the UIMA framework, I want to know how to go about it.

I understand that UIMA can annotate specific parts of the file, but how do I extract the information efficiently? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jatin

Comment: There are different components that support such a functionality, but maybe it more efficient to just apply a fast xml parser that provided access to the offsets of the elements and create annotations for the interesting parts.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what components provide this functionality within UIMA? Who knows, I may find a component that is more powerful for my use case than custom XML parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the limited perspective of a developer of [UIMA Ruta](http://uima.apache.org/ruta.html), I use the [HtmlAnnotator](http://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.html) of UIMA Ruta for these use cases. This is certainly not the most efficient approach. The analysis engine won't use separate types for the elements as it knows only the most common html tags, but I perform the conversion to a predefined type system in UIMA Ruta if needed. At the backend, the [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) is applied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also wanted to know if there is a way to extract values by providing regex and associate metadata with the value, which should be the nearest text element. In short can we map key value pairs by using uima ? For eg. In a course marksheet I provide regex for certain student registration ID and am able to extract the relevant data while associating the key, i.e. student registration Id to it.Please help.

Comment: That should not be complicated. You can define a new type with two features, key and value. Then, a simple java analysis engine using regexp should suffice. I personally would again use UIMA Ruta, which should provide all functionality needed for this task.

Comment: Thank you Peter. It helped.Also I was curious that is UIMA ruta limited to text input? Could we apply rules on form based input such as some scanned image files?

Comment: Yes, UIMA Ruta is restricted to textual files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a collection reader to get you started with:

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.uima.UimaContext;
import org.apache.uima.collection.CollectionException;
import org.apache.uima.fit.descriptor.TypeCapability;
import org.apache.uima.jcas.JCas;
import org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.Text;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
import org.jdom2.xpath.XPathExpression;
import org.jdom2.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;



@TypeCapability(outputs = "xxx")
public class XmlCollectionReader extends JCasCollectionReader_ImplBase {
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XmlCollectionReader.class);

    private SAXBuilder builder;
    private XMLOutputter xo;
    private XPathExpression<Object> sentenceXPath;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UimaContext context) throws ResourceInitializationException {
        super.initialize(context);
        try {
            File corpusDir = new File(inputDir);
            checkArgument(corpusDir.exists());
            fileIterator = DirectoryIterator.get(directoryIterator, corpusDir, "xml", false);
            builder = new SAXBuilder();
            xo = new XMLOutputter();
            xo.setFormat(Format.getRawFormat());
            sentenceXPath = XPathFactory.instance().compile("//S");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ResourceInitializationException(
                    ResourceInitializationException.NO_RESOURCE_FOR_PARAMETERS,
                    new Object[] { inputDir });
        }
    }

    public void getNext(JCas jcas) throws IOException, CollectionException {

        File file = fileIterator.next();
        try {
            LOG.debug("reading {}", file.getName());
            Document doc = builder.build(new FileInputStream(file));
            Element rootNode = doc.getRootElement();

            String title = xo.outputString(rootNode.getChild("Title").getContent());

            for (Object sentence : sentenceXPath.evaluate(rootNode)) {
                Element sentenceE = (Element) sentence;
                    ...
                }
            }

            jcas.setDocumentText(...);

        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            throw new CollectionException(e);
        }
    }
}
```